# Request for tags

Tags: support, tags

Since I am new to the site, I don't have enough rep to create tags. I have a question that could really use the tags "redemption" "artifacts" and "fortresses" and even possibly "rules-clarification".

Not sure if you want the rules-clarification one, but I would like to ask a question regarding the Redemption TCG.

Comment: rules clarification is a poor tag choice. No one (well, except maybe [this guy](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/1873/user1873)) can be an expert in "rules-clarification". If you're good at clarifying rules in one game, it's unlikely that experience well help you with other games' rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask your question, don't stress about the tags.  It'll work itself out.

There are plenty of folks who will tag a question for you.

Use whatever tag you wish to create your question if there is no suitable tag that exists already.

In general, we're big on game specific tags, and not as much about other tags.

Comment: The problem is I can't put the tags on my question. I don't have enough rep. I have also searched for tags similar to what I'm asking and they also don't exist. I can ask my question, but I can't tag it with anything related to what I am asking. My hope was to have the above tags created because I have a rules questions about artifacts and fortresses within the Redemption TCG game.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich - I mean "Use whatever tag you wish" above very literally. Use `magic-the-gathering`, use `dominion`, it doesn't matter.  Tags cannot be created without a question to put them on.  Any tags that are wrong will be fixed very quickly by those with the rep to do so.

Comment: will do. I guess I'm just used to dba.stackexchange.com where they will create tags for the users asking for them.

Comment: @Chris Aldrich - See also http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/how-to-tag-unlisted-games

Comment: Is there no tag that fits already?  (I don't recognize the ones you listed, so I don't know if those are games, expansions, rules variants, or what.  If they're expansions/variants, tag with the parent game.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Redemption is a TCG. Artifacts and fortresses are card types/elements within the game.